# How to use expression to set margins using \hoffset in TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

```
\def\leftmargin{1.25in}          % custom margin
\hoffset \leftmargin - 1in       % subtract 1in from \leftmargin, !Not working
\hoffset \leftmargin minus1in    % also tried this with no success


% In effect, \hoffset should be 0.25in
```

How do I use simple expression while setting dimensions in Plain TeX?

Comment: Welcome ` Check `\newdimen\leftmargin \leftmargin=1.25in` instead of `\def\leftmargin`

Comment: But, `-1in` is literally printed on page. Subtraction has not occured. i.e. margin is still 1.25in.

Comment: You can use \dimexpr

Comment: `\hoffset \leftmargin \advance \hoffset -1in`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Knuth's original TeX (`tex`):

```tex
\newdimen\leftmargin
\leftmargin=1.25in
\hoffset=\leftmargin
\advance\hoffset by -1in
\showthe\hoffset
```

With e-TeX (`etex`, `pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`):

```tex
\def\leftmargin{1.25in}
\hoffset=\dimexpr\leftmargin - 1in
\showthe\hoffset
```

Both give an output of

```
> 18.0675pt.
```

which is the same as `0.25in`.

Answer (score 5):

With OpTeX:

```
\hoffset=1.25in
```

That is all. The left margin will be `1.25in` after such setting, because OpTeX removes the "1in confusion" and "wasted calculation", because it sets the original point (0,0) to the upper-left corner of the paper sheet directly.